# Can't print entire data set with fits from astropy.io

Tags: python-3.x, astropy, fits

I have a large fits file (21.4 MB). I would like to print the contents of it to a text file, but can only access a portion of it. I am looking for help getting the entire file to text format.

```
> from astropy.io import fits
> hdulist = fits.open('N20190326G0041i.fits')
```

Information on the file. Note that everything is in the primary HDU.

```
> hdulist.info()  
Filename: N20190326G0041i.fits  
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format  
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     183   (190685, 28)   float32
```

I can access the full header but it is extremely long. I included it at the end of this post.

```
> hdu = hdulist[0]  
> hdu.header
```

However, I only get a portion of the data using hdu.data

```
> hdu.data
array([[ 4.0630740e+02,  4.0631021e+02,  4.0631290e+02, ...,
         1.0478779e+03,  1.0478831e+03,  1.0478882e+03],
       [ 2.7955999e+01,  3.1493999e+01,  1.2378000e+01, ...,
        -4.3614998e+00, -1.8785000e+00, -8.8672000e-01],
       [ 2.8534999e+00,  2.8862000e+00,  2.9282999e+00, ...,
        -6.1020999e+00, -5.2989998e+00, -5.1680999e+00],
       ...,
       [ 1.7951000e+04,  2.9099000e+04,  3.5257000e+03, ...,
         1.0594000e+03,  7.9347998e+02,  1.6349001e+02],
       [ 3.1568999e+03,  3.1631001e+03,  3.2426001e+03, ...,
         3.2828000e+02,  3.2062000e+02,  3.2189001e+02],
       [ 3.3338000e+03,  3.3806001e+03,  3.4557000e+03, ...,
         2.1803000e+02,  2.2574001e+02,  2.3003999e+02]], dtype=float32)
```

What I typically do to print fits files to text files is ...

```
> table = hdulist[0].data
> print(table, file = open('test.txt','a'))
```

This "works", and outputs the same excerpt of the data that hdu.data prints on screen.

```
> [[ 4.0630740e+02  4.0631021e+02  4.0631290e+02 ...  1.0478779e+03
   1.0478831e+03  1.0478882e+03]
 [ 2.7955999e+01  3.1493999e+01  1.2378000e+01 ... -4.3614998e+00
  -1.8785000e+00 -8.8672000e-01]
 [ 2.8534999e+00  2.8862000e+00  2.9282999e+00 ... -6.1020999e+00
  -5.2989998e+00 -5.1680999e+00]
 ...
 [ 1.7951000e+04  2.9099000e+04  3.5257000e+03 ...  1.0594000e+03
   7.9347998e+02  1.6349001e+02]
 [ 3.1568999e+03  3.1631001e+03  3.2426001e+03 ...  3.2828000e+02
   3.2062000e+02  3.2189001e+02]
 [ 3.3338000e+03  3.3806001e+03  3.4557000e+03 ...  2.1803000e+02
   2.2574001e+02  2.3003999e+02]]
```

Also, I repeated all of the above things using memmap = True, but get the same results.

```
> from astropy.io import fits
> hdulist = fits.open('N20190326G0041i.fits', memmap = True)
```

I also tried the convenience functions, but that produced the exact same excerpt as hdu.data.

```
> tbdata = fits.getdata('N20190326G0041i.fits')
> print(tbdata,file=open('test.txt','a'))
```

I also tried the astropy.table package, but could not get it to work either.

```
> from astropy.table import Table
> t = Table.read(hdulist[0], format = 'fits')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/table/connect.py", line 52, in __call__
    out = registry.read(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/registry.py", line 523, in read
    data = reader(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/connect.py", line 195, in read_table_fits
    memmap=memmap)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 151, in fitsopen
    lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 390, in fromfile
    lazy_load_hdus=lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 1039, in _readfrom
    fileobj = _File(fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap, cache=cache)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/utils/decorators.py", line 521, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._open_filelike(fileobj, mode, overwrite)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py", line 533, in _open_filelike
    "method, required for mode '{}'.".format(self.mode))
OSError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'.
```

However, if I use

```
> t=Table.read(hdu.data, format='fits')
```

then I get a different error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/table/connect.py", line 52, in __call__
    out = registry.read(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/registry.py", line 523, in read
    data = reader(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/connect.py", line 195, in read_table_fits
    memmap=memmap)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 147, in fitsopen
    if not name:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have also tried tprint and tdump in PyRAF, it simply gives the error "Warning: ", with no other helpful information. I also tried writing the fits file to text using the wspectext function in PyRaf, but it is unable to do so.

However, I want to be able to just use the fits package from astropy to output the data to a text file. I have done this countless times with other fits files from a variety of telescope pipelines, but it isn't working this time. Any help is much appreciated.

The header of the file is below. I'm wondering since the header was written in IDL if the only way I'll be able to access the info is through IDL? This seems unlikely to me. I'd really rather avoid using IDL if possible. We have a site license at our university, but we are not permitted on campus during the pandemic and our VPN capabilities are lacking.

```
> hdu.header  
SIMPLE  =                    T / Written by IDL:    
BITPIX  =                  -32 / Real*4 (complex, stored as float)              
NAXIS   =                    2 / Number of axes                                 
NAXIS1  =               190685 / Number of pixel columns                        
NAXIS2  =                   28 / Number of pixel rows                           
INHERIT =                    F / No need to inherit global keywords             
BZERO   =                   0. / Data is Unsigned Integer                       
BSCALE  =                   1. / Scale factor                                                  
IMAGESWV= 'CFHT DetCom v3.60.18 (Apr 20 2017)' / Image creation software version
OBSTYPE = 'OBJECT  '           / Observation / Exposure type                    
EXPTYPE = 'OBJECT  '           / See OBSTYPE                                    
EXPTIME =               2561.0 / Integration time (seconds)                     
DARKTIME=               2561.0 / Dark current time (seconds)                           
DETECTOR= 'OLAPA   '           / Science Detector                               
CCD     = 'Unknown '           / Science Detector (use DETECTOR)                
IMAGEID =                    0 / CCD chip number                                
CHIPID  =                    0 / Use IMAGEID instead                            
DETSIZE = '[1:2048,1:4608]'    / Total data pixels in full mosaic               
RASTER  = 'FULL    '           / Active raster description                      
CCDSUM  = '1 1     '           / Binning factors                                
CCDBIN1 =                    1 / Binning factor along first axis                
CCDBIN2 =                    1 / Binning factor along second axis               
PIXSIZE =                 13.5 / Pixel size for both axes (microns)             
AMPLIST = 'a,b     '           / List of amplifiers for this image              
CCDSIZE = '[1:2048,1:4608]'    / Detector imaging area size                     
CCDSEC  = '[21:2068,1:4608]'   / Read out area of the detector (unbinned)       
TRIMSEC = '[21:2068,4:4605]'   / Useful imaging area of the detector            
BSECA   = '[1:20,1:4608]'      / Overscan/prescan (bias) area from Amp A        
BSECB   = '[2069:2088,1:4608]' / Overscan/prescan (bias) area from Amp B        
CSECA   = '[21:1044,1:4608]'   / Section in full CCD for DSECA                  
CSECB   = '[1045:2068,1:4608]' / Section in full CCD for DSECB                  
DSECA   = '[21:1044,1:4608]'   / Imaging area from Amp A                        
DSECB   = '[1045:2068,1:4608]' / Imaging area from Amp B                        
TSECA   = '[21:1044,4:4605]'   / Trim section for Amp A                         
TSECB   = '[1045:2068,4:4605]' / Trim section for Amp B                         
MAXLIN  =                65535 / Maximum linearity value (ADU)                  
SATURATE=                65535 / Saturation value (ADU)                         
GAINA   =                 1.10 / Amp A gain (electrons/ADU)                     
GAINB   =                 1.20 / Amp B gain (electrons/ADU)                     
RDNOISEA=                 2.90 / Amp A read noise (electrons)                   
RDNOISEB=                 2.90 / Amp B read noise (electrons)                   
DARKCUR =                    0 / Dark current (e-/pixel/hour)                   
RDTIME  =                30.00 / Read out time (sec)                            
CONSWV  = 'olD=137,DCU=49'     / Controller software DSPID and SERNO versions   
DETSTAT = 'ok      '           / Detector temp range (-105..-90)                
DETTEM  =               -100.2 / Detector temp deg C = 745.502 + -0.278 * 3042  
INSTRUME= 'GRACES  '           / Instrument Name                                
ECAMFOC =                -3.61 / ESPaDOnS camera focus position (mm)            
EHARTPOS= 'OUT     '           / ESPaDOnS hartmann position FULL/DOWN/UP/OUT    
EEMSHUT = 'CLOSE   '           / ESPaDOnS exposure meter shutter OPEN/CLOSED    
EEMSTATE= 'OFF     '           / ESPaDOnS exposure meter state ON/OFF           
EEMCNTS =                -9999 / ESPaDOnS exposure meter count average          
ETSP1BEG=                17.38 / ESPaDOnS down mirror temp at start (deg C)     
ETSP2BEG=                17.61 / ESPaDOnS camera temp at start (deg C)          
ETSP3BEG=                17.55 / ESPaDOnS up mirror temp at start (deg C)       
ETSP4BEG=                17.31 / ESPaDOnS hygrometer temp at start (deg C)      
EPRSPBEG=                -3.35 / ESPaDOnS relative pressure at start (mb)       
ERHSPBEG=                21.11 / ESPaDOnS relative humidity at start (%)        
ETSP1END=                17.38 / ESPaDOnS down mirror temp at end (deg C)       
ETSP2END=                17.59 / ESPaDOnS camera temp at end (deg C)            
ETSP3END=                17.55 / ESPaDOnS up mirror temp at end (deg C)         
ETSP4END=                17.31 / ESPaDOnS hygrometer temp at end (deg C)        
EPRSPEND=                -3.29 / ESPaDOnS relative pressure at end (mb)         
EREADSPD= 'Slow: 2.90e noise, 1.15e/ADU, 30s' / ESPaDOnS det read out xslow/slow
GSLIPOS = 'TWOSLICE'           / GRACES slicer bench position (# and mm)        
GSLICER = 'TWOSLICE'           / GRACES slicer position (# and deg)             
GDEKKER = 'TWOSLICE'           / GRACES dekker position (# and mm)              
GPMIRROR= 'GEMINI  '           / GRACES pickoff mirror position (# and mm)      
GFIBMODE= 'GRACES  '           / GRACES fiber position (ESPADONS or GRACES)     
O_BSCALE=              1.00000 / Original BSCALE Value                          
RAWIQ   = '85-percentile'      /Raw Image Quality                               
RAWCC   = '50-percentile'      /Raw Cloud Cover                                 
RAWWV   = '20-percentile'      /Raw Water Vapour/Transparency                   
RAWBG   = '50-percentile'      /Raw Background                                  
TELESCOP= 'Gemini-North'       /Gemini-North                                    
EPOCH   =              2000.00 /Epoch for Target coordinates                    
CRPA    =        80.7411581783 /Current Cass Rotator Position Angle             
AIRMASS = '1.271   '           /Mean airmass for the observation                
AMSTART = '1.365   '           /Airmass at start of exposure                    
AMEND   = '1.191   '           /Airmass at end of exposure                      
HA      = '-03:02:41.87'       /Hour Angle Sexagesimal                          
HAD     = '-3.0449640'         /Hour Angle Decimal                              
OBSCLASS= 'science '           /Observe class                                   
INSTMODE= 'Spectroscopy, star+sky' /Observing mode                                                         
RAWPIREQ= 'YES     '           /PI Requirements Met                             
RAWGEMQA= 'USABLE  '           /Gemini Quality Assessment                       
COMMENT ----------------------------------------------------                    
COMMENT | Processed by the CFHT OPERA Open Source Pipeline |                    
COMMENT ----------------------------------------------------                    
COMMENT opera-1.0.1228 build date Fri May 19 18:53:30 HST 2017                  
COMMENT Processing Date                                                         
COMMENT ---------------                                                         
COMMENT Mon May  4 14:50:27 HST 2020                                            
COMMENT ------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMENT 20                                                                      
SNR22   = '0.50798 / 0.61051'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR23   = '0.84309 / 1.0133'   / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR24   = '1.2171 / 1.4627'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR25   = '1.9608 / 2.3567'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR26   = '2.1154 / 2.5425'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR27   = '2.1107 / 2.5368'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR28   = '2.2236 / 2.6725'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR29   = '2.1241 / 2.5528'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR30   = '2.2457 / 2.6991'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR31   = '1.9948 / 2.3975'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR32   = '1.6974 / 2.04'      / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR33   = '1.4978 / 1.8001'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR34   = '1.2949 / 1.5562'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR35   = '1.3562 / 1.63'      / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR36   = '1.0198 / 1.2257'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR37   = '1.5021 / 1.8053'    / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR38   = '1.01 / 1.2139'      / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR39   = '0.71061 / 0.85405'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR40   = '0.59577 / 0.71603'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR41   = '0.62022 / 0.74541'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR42   = '0.57458 / 0.69056'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR43   = '0.52749 / 0.63397'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR44   = '0.49149 / 0.5907'   / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR45   = '0.48021 / 0.57714'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR46   = '0.50494 / 0.60687'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR47   = '0.52551 / 0.63159'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR48   = '0.5106 / 0.61367'   / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR49   = '0.42632 / 0.51237'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR50   = '0.42451 / 0.5102'   / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR51   = '0.42025 / 0.50508'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR52   = '0.41137 / 0.49441'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR53   = '0.41708 / 0.50127'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR54   = '0.41904 / 0.50362'  / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
SNR55   = '0.4284 / 0.51487'   / snr per spectral / ccd bin                     
HRV     =              -8.9311 / Heliocentric RV correction (km/s)              
HRVLUNAR=            0.0125599 / lunar component of HRV correction (km/s)       
HRVORBIT=             -9.19911 / orbital component of HRV correction (km/s)     
HRVDIURN=             0.255451 / diurnal component of HRV correction (km/s)     
HJDUTC  =        2458568.79603 / Heliocentric Julian date (UTC) mid-exposure    
HJDTT   =       2458568.796831 / Heliocentric Julian date (TT) mid-exposure     
TELLRV  =                   0. / telluric RV correction (km/s)                  
TELLERR =                   0. / telluric RV correction error (km/s)            
REDUCTIO= 'Intensity'          / Type of reduction                              
NORMAL  = '2       '           / Normalized and Un-normalized Data              
COMMENT File contains automatic wavelength correction and uncorrected data.     
COL1    = 'Wavelength'         / Normalized                                     
COL2    = 'Star    '           / Normalized                                     
COL3    = 'Sky     '           / Normalized                                     
COL4    = 'Star+sky'           / Normalized                                     
COL5    = 'ErrorBarStar'       / Normalized                                     
COL6    = 'ErrorBarSky'        / Normalized                                     
COL7    = 'ErrorBarStar+Sky'   / Normalized                                     
COL8    = 'Wavelength'         / UnNormalized                                   
COL9    = 'Star    '           / UnNormalized                                   
COL10   = 'Sky     '           / UnNormalized                                   
COL11   = 'Star+sky'           / UnNormalized                                   
COL12   = 'ErrorBarStar'       / UnNormalized                                   
COL13   = 'ErrorBarSky'        / UnNormalized                                   
COL14   = 'ErrorBarStar+Sky'   / UnNormalized                                   
COL15   = 'Wavelength'         / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL16   = 'Star    '           / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL17   = 'Sky     '           / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL18   = 'Star+sky'           / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL19   = 'ErrorBarStar'       / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL20   = 'ErrorBarSky'        / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL21   = 'ErrorBarStar+Sky'   / Normalized, no autowave correction             
COL22   = 'Wavelength'         / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL23   = 'Star    '           / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL24   = 'Sky     '           / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL25   = 'Star+sky'           / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL26   = 'ErrorBarStar'       / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL27   = 'ErrorBarSky'        / UnNormalized, no autowave correction           
COL28   = 'ErrorBarStar+Sky'   / UnNormalized, no autowave correction
```

Comment: The data in FITS files (e.g. `hdulist[0]`) are returned as Numpy arrays. Numpy is a core library to many scientific Python packages for working with binary array-like data. This is good to be aware of because it's not specific to Astropy or FITS, and any question about how to work with data from FITS files (that isn't Astronomy-specific) is really a question about Numpy. Numpy has a built-in function [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for this purpose.

Comment: There are a couple reasons your attempts to use `Table.read` failed. For one, your data does not appear to be tabular, so this wouldn't be appropriate for CCD data in this form. Second `Table.read` is a more abstract function that just takes the name of a file (or a "file-like object, meaning something that has the same interface of the file objects returned from Python's built-in `open` function). It automatically guesses how to read the tabular data by recognizing some supported file formats. You were passing it objects it doesn't know what to do with, hence getting seemingly obscure errors.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything else I can clarify :)

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut, to be honest it didn't occur to me to consider that. I'd never had a fits file not respond to one of those methods before. Followup question about np.savetxt: when specifying _X_ (the data array to write out), how is that defined if the desired data array is within a fits file? I'm looking up examples, but they are specifying their own arrays using np.arange(). I already have a (190685, 28) array stuck inside the fits file. Is there a better numpy function to use when writing out from a file?

Comment: `astropy.io.fits` is just a library that parses the FITS file and provides access to the data as a Numpy array. You're close. You already have access to the array as you've already seen yourself. `hdulist[0].data` *is* the data in the (primary HDU) of the FITS file wrapped in the Numpy array format https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/#working-with-image-data

Comment: Ah, of course! This worked and the array was written to a text file! Thanks!

Comment: In that case I think I'll convert my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they seemed to help I'm rewriting my above comments as an answer:

The data in FITS files (e.g. `hdulist[0].data`) are returned as Numpy arrays. Numpy is a core library to many scientific Python packages for working with binary array-like data. This is good to be aware of because it's not specific to Astropy or FITS, and any question about how to work with data from FITS files (that isn't Astronomy-specific) is really a question about Numpy. Numpy has a built-in function [np.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for this purpose.  E.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.savetxt(hdulist[0].data)
```

`np.savetxt` takes numerous options you can read about in the API documentation for how to format your data.

(Side question: Why do you want to save it as a plain text file?  It seems like an fairly large array--is there something you want to do with it as a text file that you can't in binary?)

Second, are a couple reasons your attempts to use [`Table.read`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/io.html#getting-started) failed. For one, your data does not appear to be tabular, so this wouldn't be appropriate for CCD data in this form. Second `Table.read` is a more abstract function that just takes the name of a file (or a "file-like object, meaning something that has the same interface of the file objects returned from Python's built-in open function). It automatically guesses how to read the tabular data by recognizing some supported file formats. You were passing it objects it doesn't know what to do with, hence getting seemingly obscure errors.

For example `Table.read` is used like this:

```
>>> Table.read('path/to/fits/file/containing/table.fits')
```

Under the hood this is using the `astropy.io.fits` package to parse the FITS file and extract table contents.  The interface is designed to abstract away those details from the user.  In your first attempt you passed it an actual HDU object (`hdulist[0]`).  Since you specified `format='fits'` it tries to use its FITS reader on this object, but it doesn't know what to do with it because it's not a filename or a file-like object.  Similar problem with your second attempt.

Finally for the reason this didn't work as you were hoping:

```
>>> tbdata = fits.getdata('N20190326G0041i.fits')
>>> print(tbdata,file=open('test.txt','a'))
```

This is no different from `print(tbdata)`.  When you print a Numpy array to the screen it has a standard print representation which for large arrays normally truncates the data.  Using `file=` doesn't do anything magic: It just outputs the same thing you would get printing the array to the terminal, but it outputs that text to a file instead of the screen.